# Label is getting displayed below checkbox

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, view-helpers

```
<%= f.check_box :openid_enabled %>
<%= f.label :openid_enabled, 'OpenID' %>
```

Above code generate this HTML

```
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="application[openid_enabled]">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="application[openid_enabled]" id="application_openid_enabled">
<label for="application_openid_enabled">OpenID</label>
```

and the label is getting displayed like

```
[x]
OpenID
```

instead of

```
[x] OpenID
```

Do I need to style it or rails helpers have some build in functionality?

**Added**

I am using [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) CSS framework in my Rails application.

Comment: Please include the relevant CSS. The code you provided works as you want: http://jsfiddle.net/A2Y5d/

Comment: @MyHeadHurts thanks. I styled the label with with display:inline as suggested by Dipaks in below answer and it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used following to fix the issue without overriding style of twitter bootstrap css.

```
<%= f.label :openid_enabled, class: 'checkbox' do %>
  <%= f.check_box :openid_enabled %>
  OpenID
<% end %>
```

Which generates following HTML

```
<label for="application_openid_enabled" class="checkbox">
  <input type="hidden" value="0" name="application[openid_enabled]">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="application[openid_enabled]" id="application_openid_enabled">
  OpenID
</label>
```

Here is reference http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html

Thanks @MyHeadHurts and @Dipaks for your invaluable inputs.

Comment: +1 - since you are using Twitter Bootstrap this is the right way to do it

Answer (score 5):

This must be happening because either `input` or `label` is set as `display: block;` You can show it in one line by making these elements `inline` -

```
input, label{ display: inline; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know its old but the best way to do it today would be to use the [checkbox-inline class](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_form_checkbox_inline) on the label.