# How to keep a checkbox and label on the same line in a Rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3

What should I do to keep the label of a checkbox on the same line with the checkbox in a rails view containing a form?

Currently the label goes on the next line:

```
<div class="span6 offset3">
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <br>
  <%= f.check_box :terms_of_service %>
  <%= f.label :terms_of_service, "I agree to the #{link_to 'Terms of Service', policies_path}.".html_safe %>
  <br><br>

  <%= f.submit "Create my account", :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Thank you,
Alexandra

Comment: I found this link, I think you can apply this into your code.
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306252/how-to-align-checkboxes-and-their-labels-consistently-cross-browsers>

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12037003/517483

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It looks like you're using Bootstrap, so I recommend adapting your view code to use the horizontal form layout described in this section of the Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#horizontal-form

Comment: I ended up using the Bootstrap docs, as David Underwood recommended. Once I added `:class => "checkbox inline"` to my label, the label stayed on the same line with the checkbox.

Comment: This comment should be a separate answer. Its better than the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, this comment is the way to do it in Rails. The bootstrap solution assumes you can wrap a label tag around an input, which rails does not do. The top comment here works

Comment: Every answer here is wrong. The correct code is `<label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
    </label>`

Comment: If anyone's using simple_form to try to accomplish this:  `<%= f.input :terms_of_service, inline_label: "I agree ...", label: false %>` generates: `<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"/>I agree ...</label>`

Comment: Benoît Legat's answer below is correct. You CAN wrap a form input in a label with Rails. You just have to open a block like this: `<%= f.label :attribute do %>`

Comment: FYR "checkbox-inline" is the classname not "checkbox inline". Not sure if this is just a ruby translation issue.

Comment: @Alexandra you should post `:class => "checkbox inline"` into a separate answer and accept it. This is not a answer. Your comment has more upvotes than most answers here

Answer (score 64):

According to the [bootstrap wiki](https://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#forms), it must be

```
<label class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
</label>
```

which in Ruby on Rails is

```
<%= f.label :terms_of_service do %>
  <%= f.check_box :terms_of_service %>
  I agree to the <%= link_to 'Terms of Service', policies_path %>.
<% end %>
```

Comment: Same problem here. I followed this to wrap `f.check_box` in `f.label`, and it's now aligned.

Comment: thanks! this is what I needed from the above answer where it was stated in a comment that Rails doesn't allow wrapping an input in a label

Comment: For other readers. You you want to have the label ***before*** the checkbox, the text will come before `f.check_box`

Answer (score 5):

```
 <br>
  <%= f.check_box :terms_of_service, :style => "float:left;" %>
  <%= f.label :terms_of_service, "I agree to the #{link_to 'Terms of Service', policies_path}.".html_safe, :style => "float:left;" %>
  <br>
```

Comment: = f.input :income, :label => "Income?", :input_html => {:style => "float:left"}

Answer (score 5):

The comment on the answer is correct, but it assumes some nuance of understanding about order of elements.

The correct answer is as follows:

```
<%= f.check_box :terms_of_service %>
<%= f.label :terms_of_service, "I agree to the #{link_to 'Terms of Service', policies_path}.".html_safe
                             , {class: "checkbox inline"} %>
```

Two things are necessary:

1. The class on the label element
2. The checkbox element has to be before the label element.

This is obvious once you see it working, but all the other samples for form_for always have the inputs after the labels and you need to change that up for checkbox.

Answer (score 3):

```
  <div class="form-inline">
    <%= f.check_box :subscribed, class: 'form-control' %>
    <%= f.label :subscribed, "Subscribe" %>
  </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please try to add a sentence or two when providing an answer. Best regards

Answer (score 2):

i had a similar problem the other day, im using twitter bootsrap, but im also using the simple_form gem. i had to fix that detail through css, here is my code:

```
<%=f.input :status, :label => "Disponible?",  :as => :boolean, :label_html => { :class => "pull-left dispo" }%>
```

css:

```
.dispo{
    margin-right:10%;
}
pull-left{
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To keep the i18n using of `label`, you can use `t`:

```
<%= f.label :my_field do %>
  <%= f.check_box :my_field %> <%= t 'activerecord.attributes.my_model.my_field' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would wrap the check box inside the label.

```
  <%= f.label :terms_of_service do %>
    <%= f.check_box :terms_of_service %>
    I agree to the <%= link_to 'Terms of Service', policies_path %>
  <% end %>
```

When the input field is wrapped by it's label, you actually don't need the for attribute on the label. The label will activate the check box without it on click. So even simpler:

```
  <label>
    <%= f.check_box :terms_of_service %>
    I agree to the <%= link_to 'Terms of Service', policies_path %>
  </label>
```

Generically for Rails, this could be a way to go about it (human_attribute_name works with i18n):

```
<label>
  <%= f.check_box :terms_of_service %>
  <%= User.human_attribute_name(:terms_of_service) %>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

for basic rails tags:

```
<%= label_tag('retry-all') do %>
  Retry All
  <= check_box_tag("retry-all",false) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use `bootstrap`? 
Easy way to do is add `:class => "span1"` in f.submit. I'm sure it worked!

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap 4, in HAML

```
  .form-check
    =f.label :decision_maker, class: 'form-check-label' do
      =f.check_box :decision_maker, class: 'form-check-input'
      Decision Maker
```

or

```
  .form-group
    =f.check_box :decision_maker
    =f.label :decision_maker
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#default-stacked

> `<div class="form-check">
>         <label class="form-check-label">
>           <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="">
>           Option one is this and that&mdash;be sure to include why it's great
>         </label>
>       </div>`

The first way is the more correct way, but the second way looks virtually identical and DRYer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <%= f.label :paid? %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <%= f.check_box :paid, value: 'false'  %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to add a comment or description to your answer

Answer (score 0):

On Rails 5.2, ruby 2.4 and bootstrap 4.1.1:

```
<%= form.check_box :terms_of_service, label: "your custom label...."%>
```

worked for me without having to indicate inline checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me -I use flex

CSS file

```
.checkbox-container-outer{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
}

.checkbox-container-inner{
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

RAILS VIEW

```
<div class="checkbox-container-outer">
 <div class="checkbox-container-inner">
   <%= form.checkbox_field :remember_me
 </div>
 <div>
   <%= form.label :remember_me
 </div>
</div>
```

[image: How it looks on my site]

Answer (score -2):

I use pure CSS/HTML and this CSS works well for me.

```
input {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
}
label {
    display: inline;
}
```